# How to know whether a video is played completly?

Tags: javascript, html, video, popcornjs

I want to know whether the video has compltely played or not for this I have an idea that after end of video if the currenttime and duration of the video  (using javascript) are same we can confirm it as video has played completely. But I cant frame it. Another thing is that are there any direct methods to known whether a video is played till end or not?

thanks in advance

awaiting replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 < video > tag (let's suppose it has "myVideo" as ID) you can get/set its time with the command

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.currentTime = 5;
alert(vid.currentTime);
```

and video duration with

```
alert(vid.duration)
```

There's also a *direct* way to check if a video, by adding a Javascript listener.

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    if(!e){
        e = window.event;
    }
    alert("Ended."); //Replace this with the code you need to execute when video ends
}
```

Sources and examples: [currentTime](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp), [duration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp).

Comment: still are there any direct properties to know it.

Comment: You can add a JavaScript listener, I'll update the answer so that it's complete.